# Tarpaulin flagging line as not covered

Tags: rust, code-coverage

I'm literally just starting with Rust so I'm sure this is a naïve question but it's got me stupmed.

In the (simplified) example below, the test passes just fine but [Tarpaulin](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-tarpaulin) is flagging that the line `.values` (between `let data = self` & `.iter()`), and only this line, is uncovered. I don't get why that would be and any explanation would be gratefully accepted. Being so new, I'm inclined to assume that I'm not testing correctly.

Thanks

```
use std::ops::Add;

struct Series<T> {
    // Other Stuff
    values: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> Series<T> {
    pub fn new(values: Vec<T>) -> Series<T> {
        Series { values }
    }
}

impl<T> Add<&Series<T>> for &Series<T>
where
    T: Add + Add<Output = T> + Copy,
{
    type Output = Series<T>;

    fn add(self, rhs: &Series<T>) -> Series<T> {
        let data = self
            .values
            .iter()
            .zip(rhs.values.iter())
            .map(|(&a, &b)| a + b)
            .collect();
        Series::new(data)
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn add() {
        let s1 = Series::new(vec![1, 2, 3]);
        let s2 = Series::new(vec![4, 5, 6]);
        let s3 = &s1 + &s2;
        assert_eq!(s3.values, vec![5, 7, 9]);
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Currently, tarpaulin provides working line coverage and while fairly reliable may still contain minor inaccuracies in the results.*"

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll log it as an issue on their GitHub project. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something stupid first!

Answer (score 0):

***Not offering a solution to the problem here,but tries to give an explanation to the phenomena***

For the code at any line to be covered the compiler must be generate a CPU instruction for it. It looks in this case as the compiler is not generating any extra instructions to fetch the vector from the object variable.

To observe this phenomena one could turn up the optimization level and see how less lines gets covered by the same code. With `opt-level=2`,then lines 9, 20-22 and 24 does not yield any assembly instructions for the CPU thus those lines never get covered when running the tests. Turning `opt-level` back to 0 will show the same result as in the question.

*Turning on optimizations gives less coverage*

```
$ cargo tarpaulin --rustflags="-C opt-level=2"
Jul 15 14:59:54.985  INFO cargo_tarpaulin::config: Creating config
Jul 15 14:59:54.990  INFO cargo_tarpaulin: Running Tarpaulin
Jul 15 14:59:54.990  INFO cargo_tarpaulin: Building project
Jul 15 14:59:54.990  INFO cargo_tarpaulin::cargo: Cleaning project
   Compiling tarptest v0.1.0 (tarptest)
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.31s
Jul 15 14:59:55.338  INFO cargo_tarpaulin::process_handling::linux: Launching test
Jul 15 14:59:55.338  INFO cargo_tarpaulin::process_handling: running tarptest/target/debug/deps/tarptest-93760ef629d9d9ee

running 1 test
test tests::add ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.01s

Jul 15 14:59:55.482  INFO cargo_tarpaulin::report: Coverage Results:
|| Uncovered Lines:
|| src/main.rs: 9, 20-22, 24
|| Tested/Total Lines:
|| src/main.rs: 6/11 -20.45%
|| 
54.55% coverage, 6/11 lines covered, -20.45454545454546% change in coverage
```

*and with opt-level 0 only one line is not covered*

```
$ cargo tarpaulin --rustflags="-C opt-level=0"
Jul 15 15:00:06.137  INFO cargo_tarpaulin::config: Creating config
Jul 15 15:00:06.142  INFO cargo_tarpaulin: Running Tarpaulin
Jul 15 15:00:06.143  INFO cargo_tarpaulin: Building project
Jul 15 15:00:06.143  INFO cargo_tarpaulin::cargo: Cleaning project
   Compiling tarptest v0.1.0 (tarptest)
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.25s
Jul 15 15:00:06.442  INFO cargo_tarpaulin::process_handling::linux: Launching test
Jul 15 15:00:06.442  INFO cargo_tarpaulin::process_handling: running tarptest/target/debug/deps/tarptest-93760ef629d9d9ee

running 1 test
test tests::add ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.02s

Jul 15 15:00:06.566  INFO cargo_tarpaulin::report: Coverage Results:
|| Uncovered Lines:
|| src/main.rs: 22
|| Tested/Total Lines:
|| src/main.rs: 11/12 +37.12%
|| 
91.67% coverage, 11/12 lines covered, +37.12121212121212% change in coverage
```